# Convert MySQLdb.fetchall() result (strings inside tuples inside tuples) to a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a .fetchall() result like this:

`t = (('oranges',), ('apples',), ('pears',))`

How do I turn this into a dictionary like this:

`d = {'oranges':None, 'apples':None, 'pears':None}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> t = (('oranges',), ('apples',), ('pears',)    
>>> dict((item[0], None) for item in t)
{'pears': None, 'apples': None, 'oranges': None}
```

Comment: Thanks, I hope to get the hang of this one day :)

Answer (score 1):

In Python2.7 or better, the fastest way is to use a dict comprehension:

```
In [12]: {item[0]: None for item in t}
Out[12]: {'apples': None, 'oranges': None, 'pears': None}
```

For older versions of Python, there is the fromkeys method:

```
In [6]: dict.fromkeys([row[0] for row in t])
Out[6]: {'apples': None, 'oranges': None, 'pears': None}
```

---

So how to decide which one to use? If all methods are equally readable, I go with whichever one is fastest:

In [17]: t = [(str(i),) for i in range(10000)]

```
In [18]: %timeit dict((item[0], None) for item in t)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.36 ms per loop

In [19]: %timeit dict.fromkeys([row[0] for row in t])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.54 ms per loop

In [20]: %timeit {item[0]: None for item in t}
100 loops, best of 3: 2.24 ms per loop
```